# Cocoa-Touch: Check if UIViewController exists before init it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Is there a way to check if a UIViewController is loaded in memory/visible on screen?

Something like this:

```
if([ContentRvController exists]){
    contentView *ContentRvController = [[contentView alloc] 
        initWithNibName:@"contentView" bundle:nil]; //ContentView is a custom UIViewController
    ....
    //Code to set the UIViewController
    ....
}
else{
    [ContentRvController release];
}
```

That should happen when a button (that right now initializes the ViewControllers) is tapped. Right now, when tapped it opens n ViewControllers, it is supposed to display only one at a time.

Thats pretty much it, greetings and hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this based on existing code? 
Classes should start upper case, and instances should be camel case, e.g.

```
if([contentRvController exists]){
    ContentView *contentRvController = [[ContentView alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"contentView" bundle:nil]; //ContentView is a custom UIViewController
    ....
    //Code to set the UIViewController
    ....
}
else{
    [contentRvController release];
}
```

it is probably worth declaring it in the header, i.e.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {

}
@property(non-atomic, retain) ContentView *contentRvController;
@end
```

and then in code you could do

```
if(contentRvController!=nil){
    ContentView *aView=[[[ContentView alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.contentRvController=aView;
}
```

Also, don't do the else{[contentRv release];} bit, if you have autoreleased it anywhere, this will leak at some point.

Comment: Just a little problem. The snippet I post up there calls ContentView from another class. If the ContentView exists, hides the view, sets it to nil and release it, but ContentView itself has a close button that when tapped, does the same.

The problem is that when in the IBAction (inside ContentView) the `self = nil;` does not actually sets the created ContentView to nil (or at least when the `if(contentRvController = nil)` is executed, it returns false, so I have to tap twice the launch button in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UINavigationController` check for the property `topViewController`.

Comment: No, contentView is added with addSubView (maybe a little weird, but since the UIView floats on a simulated Desktop it was the only way I could find, you can drag the view and everything).